# Handling of loading indicator for multiple ajax calls in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using Polymer 1.0 to create a web application.

I have various elements doing one or more iron-ajax calls and I have another element for showing the loading-overlay. But in my current sollution I have added the loading-overlay, with its logic to show or not, to every element doing ajax calls.

```
<dom-module id="backend-call-application">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax id='loadA' loading="{{_loadingA}}" ...></iron-ajax>
    <iron-ajax id='loadB' loading="{{_loadingB}}" ...></iron-ajax>

    <loading-overlay id="loadingOverlay" with-backdrop></loading-overlay>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'backend-call-application',

      observers:[
        "_isXhrLoading(_loadingA,_loadingB,....)"
      ],

      _isXhrLoading: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          if (arguments[i]) {
            this.$.loadingOverlay.open()
            return;
          }
        }
        this.$.loadingOverlay.close()
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Now my question is, what is the best way to show such a loading-overlay?

One idea of mine would be, to have something like an observer in the loading overlay. So every element doing requests will bind its properties to the observer. These properties could be stored in an array and everytime on change, the loading-overlay checks if at least one have loading properties set to true. When one or more properties are true the loading-overlay will be opened and when all requests finished loading it will be closed.

Another idea was to use events to tell the loading-overlay when a element starts/stops loading. But here will be the problem, that I have more than one request at the same time (The first request closes the overlay, but the page hasn't finished loading).

Edit:

The `loading-overlay` is an element containing the [IronOverlayBehavior](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/behaviors/Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior).

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/iron-overlay-behavior/iron-overlay-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html">

<dom-module id="loading-overlay">
  <template>
    <paper-spinner active="true"></paper-spinner>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'loading-overlay',
      behaviors: [
        Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior
      ]
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

use one property for loading instead of 2!!

```
<iron-ajax id='loadA' loading="{{_loading}}" ...></iron-ajax>
<iron-ajax id='loadB' loading="{{_loading}}" ...></iron-ajax>
```

bind loading value to loading-overlay with some attribute and when loading is true display loader

```
 <loading-overlay id="loadingOverlay" is-loading="[[_loading]]" with-backdrop></loading-overlay>
```

so each time any ajax is made then _loading  will become true so displays loader

Comment: But what happens if both are loading and one is finished?  then the overlay should disappear but is not done loading

Comment: That's the posters question i think: what happens when ONE has another loading state than the OTHER?

Comment: And what should happen with the `is-loading` inside my `loading-overlay`?

Maybe I missed to say that the `loading-overlay` is an own element implementing the [IronOverlayBehavior](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/behaviors/Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior). But I think this element would not be able to open itself.

Comment: is-loading is added by me just for your understanding!! 
I think you should be having some attribute for that like in paper paper spinner we have active and we bing _loading to active attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you could shorten is the _isXhrLoading observer.

```
_isXhrLoading: function() {
    if(Array.from(arguments).indexOf(true) >= 0) {
        this.$.loadingOverlay.open()
    } else {
        this.$.loadingOverlay.close()
    }
  }
```

Comment: At least a small benefit when writing it to every element where it is used.

But looks very strage to me with the `indexOf(true)` when coming from the Java world :P

Comment: Checked it out, but not possible. `arguments` is not an array, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) for more information. But this will work when converting it to an array (Also shown in the link above).